# Что мешает поменять название корзины на главной странице?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, woocommerce

Пытаюсь в теме поменять название корзины на главной странице. При обновлении на доли секунды меняется на мою версию. Потом становится стандартной. Что блокирует новое названии корзины.

```
<div class="header-cart">
  <a class="header-cart-contents" href="<?php echo $woocommerce->cart->get_cart_url(); ?>" title="<?php _e('Empty cart', 'shopstar'); ?>">
    <span class="header-cart-amount">
      <?php echo sprintf(_n('%d item', '%d items', $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_count, 'shopstar'), $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_count);?> - <?php echo $woocommerce->cart->get_cart_total(); ?>
    </span>
    <span class="header-cart-checkout<?php echo ( $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_count > 0 ) ? ' cart-has-items' : ''; ?>">
      <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> <span><?php _e('Empty cart', 'shopstar'); ?></span>
    </span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Непонятно что именно менять. И где тоже. Нужна ссылка на страницу с проблемой и внятное описание что на что.

Comment: http://yonadee.com/sample-page/    текст возле корзины

Comment: Какой текст? Перевод что ли нужен?

Comment: да не перевод) в коде я поменял на свой текст) <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> <span><?php _e('Empty cart', 'shopstar'); ?></span> на empty car) а он не хочет менят

Answer (score 1):

У вас тема `shopstar`. В ней вывод в верхнюю строку производится дважды: из файла `/shopstar/library/template-parts/top-bar.php` и `/shopstar/library/includes/woocommerce-inc.php`.

Чтобы изменить вывод при первой загрузке страницы, надо [создать дочернюю тему](https://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%94%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B), в ней создать папку `/library/template-parts/`, скачать в нее файл top-bar.php и отредактировать его.

Чтобы изменить вывод в `woocommerce-inc.php`, следует скопировать все содержимое этого файла в functions.php дочерней темы, переименовать shopstar_wc_header_add_to_cart_fragment (2 вхождения) и добавить строку

```
remove_filter('add_to_cart_fragments', 'shopstar_wc_header_add_to_cart_fragment');
```

Можно, конечно, поправить оба указанных файла прямо в основной теме, но тогда при обновлении этой темы ваши правки исчезнут.

**UPDATE:**

Вывод хука `add_to_cart_fragment` сохраняется WooCommerce в cookie, поэтому для того, чтобы увидеть изменения, надо очистить cookie.

Comment: Данную тему не смотрел, но как правило файлы в подкаталогах не учитывают дочку. Кроме того они могут обновляться. Так что копирование часто приводит к некорректной работе или полной неработоспособности. В подобных случаях лучше использовать свой подключаемый шаблон шапки (get_template_part напр) или что там нужно,

Comment: KAGG, Оба файла выше отредактировал под себя) не помогает(

Comment: Поставил тему себе на тестовый сайт, работает: http://take.ms/0fmSv   Обновил ответ. Проблема в cookie.